# How to improve the purity of the question

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Cross Validated post: [How to incorporate the uncertainty of the model coefficients in the prediction interval of a multiple linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457861/how-to-incorporate-the-uncertainty-of-the-model-coefficients-in-the-prediction-i)

So what information is needed (and why: what is your intend to learn from it) such that the question can be considered for posting on the statistics stack.

Comment: There is a lot of advice and discussion at the cited thread. Asking again on Meta is certainly allowed but is in practice not especially helpful unless you can raise some extra issue, e.g.. unfair treatment in some sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, when a question is said to be unclear almost always people voting, commenting or closing to that effect are genuinely uncertain about what you want. We are not in the position of teachers who know what the answer should be and are criticising students because they don't explain clearly. It is quite uncommon in that circumstance that we can guess confidently what you really want -- and if we did, closing as unclear would not be the right outcome. People would just try to answer the question.

Comment: As I see it, I have answered/followed that advice as far as it was clear/possible to follow. Hence the reason I posted it on meta. I'm not a statistician, nor claiming to be one. I come here with a question for which I am unable to find an answer in literature. (Either because I'm not familiar with the relevant literature or because it doesn't exist. For me either case is as valid an answer as the other.)